# How to create a read-only user for a particular schema

Tags: sql-server, azure

After creating a user via `CREATE USER...` I want to give it access to my database and schema. Here is the way that is working:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'tom'
GRANT SELECT ON schema::dbo TO tom;
```

However, I'm having trouble doing this with the stored procedure, as the following doesn't give 'enough' privileges:

```
GRANT CONNECT TO tom;
GRANT SELECT ON schema::dbo TO tom;
```

What's wrong with using the `CONNECT`? What else do I need to grant such that they'll have select-all privileges on that schema?

**Update**: it seems I have to give it a more rigorous 'select'. Here is what worked:

```
GRANT CONNECT to tom;
GRANT SELECT to tom;
DENY SELET ON schema::other_schema to tom;
GRANT SELET ON schema::dbo to tom;
GO
```

Why do I need to add in the `GRANT SELECT to tom` ?

Comment: What's wrong with your stored procedure? Can you show us some code? I've created a test, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know, if we run `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'tom'`, the user will have the most privileges and can access all schemas of the current database.

I tried the following code, the user will only have the **select** privilege of the current database.

```sql
CREATE LOGIN bobby WITH PASSWORD = 'Password1'

CREATE USER bobby FOR LOGIN bobby;

GRANT CONNECT TO bobby;
GRANT SELECT ON schema::production TO bobby;
```

After I run this, I can access the specified database and the specified
schema(production) with the user bobby.

[image]

Then I run `GRANT SELECT to bobby;`, I can see the user bobby can access all the schemas in the current db.

[image]

So we can conclude that:

- `GRANT SELECT to bobby;` means grant all schemas to the user of the current database.
- `GRANT SELECT ON schema::production TO bobby;` means grant specified schema to the user of the current database.